# Change footer within the document in fancyhdr

Tags: macros, fancyhdr

I am producing LaTeX reports via Rmarkdown. The LaTeX code should therefore be generic. I would like to add arbitrary text to the existing footer *within* the document, defined in a certain pagestyle.
I tried the following:

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,notitlepage]{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\makeatletter
\fancypagestyle{custom}{%
  \fancyhf{}
  \lfoot{\footnotesize Footnote}}

\newcommand\Lfoot[1]{\lfoot{\f@ncyolf\\#1}}
\makeatother

\pagestyle{custom}

\begin{document}

Text
\Lfoot{add text to footer}

\end{document}
```

The problem is that I somehow cannot add `\f@ncyolf` to `\lfoot{}`. Each by themselves works fine, i.e. to add `\f@ncyolf` to the document or to add a text, other than `\f@ncyolf` to the footer.
How do I do this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\f@ncyolf` is an internal macro that is redefined when you change the footer via `\lfoot`. If you use this macro inside the footer text, you get a recursive definition in the end, which will make TeX go into a loop until it dies in a stack overflow.

What you can do is to define a global macro (`\myfootertext` in the example) for the basis text of your footer, and extend this text each time `\Lfoot` is called:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,notitlepage]{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\newcommand\myfootertext{\footnotesize Footnote}
\fancypagestyle{custom}{%
  \fancyhf{}
  \lfoot{\myfootnotetext}}

\newcommand\Lfoot[1]{\lfoot{\myfootertext\\#1}}

\pagestyle{custom}

\begin{document}

Text
\Lfoot{add text to footer}

\newpage

Text
\Lfoot{add other text to footer}

\end{document}
```

will print

> Footnote
>   add text to footer

on page one and

> Footnote
>   add other text to footer

on page two.

Comment: Elegant answer, thanks! You could now also remove the `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`.